# How to handle incoming POST data from external server in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, post, sendgrid

I have a route for handling incoming POST data in laravel:

```
Route::get('/sendgrid/api', 'SendGrid\EmailEventsController@parse');
```

Here's my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\SendGrid;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\SendGrid\EmailEvents;

class EmailEventsController extends Controller
{
    public function parse()
    {
        $contents = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $requests = json_decode($contents);

        $data = array();

        foreach ($requests as $request)
        {
            array_push($data, array(
                'email' => $request->email,
                'event' => $request->event,
                'category' => $request->category
            ));
        }

        EmailEvents::insert($data);
    }
}
```

But still doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: `Route::get()` that maybe?

Comment: use `::post` and add your url to `csrf` excepts.

Comment: That doesn't help. Still not working.

Comment: what is the middleware for that route? and use `post` for `POST` requests.

Comment: what do you mean by doesnt work? is there an error?

Comment: @Wreigh as you can see in the above code there is no Middleware

Comment: @saintsweeto is that in web.php or api.php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can change your route looks like this

```
Route::any('/sendgrid/api', 'SendGrid\EmailEventsController@parse');
```

And then, you must ignore for not used csrf in Middleware > VerifyCsrfToken

And add your code looks like this

```
protected $except = [
     '/sendgrid/api',
];
```

And you can used and change

```
$contents = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

to

```
$contents = $request->getContent();
```

i hope this code can help your problems. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, it's a POST request, then receive it using POST

```
Route::post('/sendgrid/api', 'SendGrid\EmailEventsController@parse');
```