# Post data to external URL

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to post data from one sperate laravel website to another laravel site.

I am sending register post request from abc.com controller to xyz.com register controller.

abc.com structure

**web.php**

```
Route::post('register','SiteController@register')->name('register');
```

**SiteController.php**

```
public function register(Request $request){
    $full_name = $request->input('full_name');
    $email_address = $request->input('email_address');
    $password = $request->input('password');

    $data = [];
    $data['full_name'] = $full_name;
    $data['email'] = $email_address;
    $data['password'] = $password;

}
```

xyz.com site structure

using https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth for login and registration.

I tried various options from requests, redirect, curl and also tried [guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)

But no luck.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle incoming POST data from external server in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045179/how-to-handle-incoming-post-data-from-external-server-in-laravel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CURL should be enough to post data to different url (in this case xyz.com). Make sure the csrf is disabled since it's a POST request from different laravel app [In Laravel 5, How to disable VerifycsrfToken middleware for specific route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223189/in-laravel-5-how-to-disable-verifycsrftoken-middleware-for-specific-route) if this still fail, check the log on laravel app

Answer (score 2):

You want Http::post

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$response = Http::post('http://example.com/users', [
    'name' => 'Steve',
    'role' => 'Network Administrator',
]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#request-data

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Explain why http::post should be used and/or what's in the link?

Comment: how to use http::post to redirect, as a http form does?

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl

[POST data to a URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080146/post-data-to-a-url-in-php)

But i think you are trying to complicate it a bit, just change action in form to external url