# handle incoming post data from external server or device in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, post

contine with the previous question [how-to-handle-incoming-post-data-from-external-server-in-laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045179/how-to-handle-incoming-post-data-from-external-server-in-laravel)

Like above I am using the route:

```
Route::post('/sendgrid/api', 'SendGrid\EmailEventsController@parse');
Route::post('/sendgrid/api/Session', 'SendGrid\EmailEventsController@parse');
```

In that case can I ignore the csrf in Middleware > VerifyCsrfToken
like this

```
protected $except = [
     '/sendgrid/api/*',
];
```

Will this also work?

I want to get fetch the data sent in json format from external server.